# Parsing and storing classes

Tags: c#, parsing

I have a class that stores items that inherit an "Item" class in a dictionary.I have a couple of classes that inherit from each other,

Example:

`Item <- Commodity <- Weapon`.

The classes are just containers, they do not have specific methods only constructors, they only hold information.

In the ItemManager class i have a method that gets passed strings that represent the name of the text file (without format). Using that format i also know what method to call to parse a line from that file into a class instance by giving the method the split line as an array.

How do i make it so that in those methods that process the items i don't have to write duplicate field assignments?

Example:

In the method that generates an item from the array i have `tmpItem.id=int.parse(line[0])` and in the method that generates a weapon i have `tmpWeapon.id = int.parse(line[0])`.

Am i doing this wrong? How do you efficiently parse a line of text into an object knowing the inheritance relation (thinking of constructors that call the base constructor).

Comment: Generate a class for items which contains the different type like weapon.  You could use a structure but structure are kind of obsolete.

Comment: I already have that, that's not what i need :)

Comment: Yes you do need it.  It the base class for item you declare the base class for the id property then you don't have to declare it again in the inherited classes.  In the inherited classes you can use any of the items in the item class.

Comment: Not what i'm asking dude..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create constructors taking file content splited into lines and call base constructor:

```
public class Base
{
    public const int LinesCount = 1;
    public Item(string[] lines)
    {
        Id = int.Parse(lines[0]);
    }

    public int Id { get; }
}

public class Inherited : Base
{
    public Inherited(string[] lines) : base(lines)
    {
        int index = base.LinesCount;
        OtherProperty = int.Parse(lines[index++]);
    }

    public int OtherProperty { get; }
}
```

**EDIT**
Added solution for changing lines count per class

Comment: I've thought of this, but an issue would be that i would have to know the index after calling the base class. Let' say i have something with 32 lines, i would only need 13 lines for the base class, then the rest for my current class. If i change something in the base class to require 16 lines, i would have to update the hard-coded 13 to 16, and there's risk of forgetting to do that :D

Comment: @Rareș: you could pass an extra offset argument, or pass only the rest of the strings. I wouldn't use constructors for this, though - having separate parse methods works just as well, without tying your classes to any particular input format: `ParseWeapon` would call `ParseCommodity`, which in turn would call `ParseItem` - each passes the item that's under construction on to the next method, as well as the lines that method needs.

Answer (score 0):

Its good that you realized that you are duplicating the parsing code and want to fix it.

If all classes inherit from Item class then move the common properties into this class and parse it from here. For example.

```
public abstract class Item
{
  public int id { get; set; }

  public virtual void ParseId(string line)
  {
    id = int.Parse(line);
  }
}
```

Now all inherited classes will have the same parsing method and they can use it but this way you can remove the duplication.

This is a simplest example which I come up with. I think next you want to have One method which can parse everything and set those properties but I don't know whats your strategy. But keep in mind if you want to remove duplication then easiest way is to move that code into base classes (although its not the best case always but I think you don't need to worry about it at this time.

Updated: After reading your comment, I've changed the code to below. it might help you with something

```
public abstract class Item
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public float volume { get; set; }
    public float minPrice { get; set; }
    public float mass { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }

    public virtual void Parse( string[] entries )
    {
        int i = 0;
        id = int.Parse( entries[ i++ ] );
        name = entries[ i++ ];
        minPrice = float.Parse( entries[ i++ ] );
        volume = float.Parse( entries[ i++ ] );
        mass = float.Parse( entries[ i++ ] );
        description = RemoveTabs( entries[ i ] );
    }

    public string RemoveTabs( string line ) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

public class Commodity : Item
{
}

public class Weapon : Commodity
{
}

public class CommodityC : Item
{
}


public class ItemManager
{

    private Item ProcessCommodity( string[] entries )
    {
        var commodity = new Commodity();
        var weapon = new Weapon();

        commodity.Parse( entries );
        //weapon.Parse( entries );
        return commodity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering here, whats the point in this being an abstract class if you arent using virtual methods or unimplemented methods

Comment: excellent point. I guess @Rares knows better if "Item" class will be instantiated or this method will be overriden in sub classes but I'll modify my code to have virtual method.

Comment: private CommodityC ProcessCommodity (string[] entries)
    {
        CommodityC tmpCommodity = new CommodityC();
        int i = 0;

        tmpCommodity.id = int.Parse(entries[i++]);
        tmpCommodity.name = entries[i++];
        tmpCommodity.minPrice = float.Parse(entries[i++]);
        tmpCommodity.volume = float.Parse(entries[i++]);
        tmpCommodity.mass = float.Parse(entries[i++]);
        tmpCommodity.description = RemoveTabs(entries[i]);

        return tmpCommodity;
    }

Comment: private WeaponC ProcessWeapon (string[] entries)
    {
        WeaponC tmpCommodity = new WeaponC();
        int i = 0;

        tmpCommodity.id = int.Parse(entries[i++]);
        tmpCommodity.name = entries[i++];
        tmpCommodity.model = FindModel(tmpCommodity.id, entries[i++]);
        tmpCommodity.minPrice = float.Parse(entries[i++]);
        tmpCommodity.volume = float.Parse(entries[i++]);
        tmpCommodity.mass = float.Parse(entries[i++]);
        tmpCommodity.description = RemoveTabs(entries[i]);

        return tmpCommodity;
    }

Comment: As you can tell they have the same structure mostly...Am I already doing this right?